# Java code error in my CSVHelper

Tags: java, eclipse, k-means

I am using the CsvHelper library to read/write csv files from my excel.  to implement K means clustering. When I run my main class there's an error 
(The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files) in the code curVal.append((char)ch);

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please add the stacktrace and code. You may also have a look at [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve the question. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.CharSequence` is part of Java since Java 1.4.

That error means that either your Java installation is missing its standard library, or it is older than 1.4 (released in 2002!)

Without further information, we cannot solve this for you, because it apparently is a problem local to *your computer*.